# Injected video src attribute via javascript not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a popup that contains a video with empty source attributes.

```
<div id="event-popup">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls id="event-popup-video">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" id="epv-mp4"></source>
    <source src="" type="video/ogg" id="epv-ogg"></source>
  </video>
</div>
```

This is used for multiple Leaflet map markers the a user can click on, which will trigger the popup to appear and then inject the correct src attribute based on the id of the clicked item.

```
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat, a.lon), {
  alt: a.cartodb_id,
  icon: starIcon,
  clickable: true
}).on('click', onClick);
```

The onClick function displays the popup and injects the correct src file location (S3 bucket item) into the .

```
function onClick(e){
  // other code to display popup
  showChangeEventVideo(e.target.options.alt);
}

function showChangeEventVideo(id){
  $("#epv-mp4").attr("src", "s3_URL_based_on_ID.mp4");
  $("#epv-ogg").attr("src", "s3_URL_based_on_ID.ogg");
}
```

The code executes, displays the popup, and inserts the correct src URL into the , but doesn't show the video. I can hard code a video URL into the  HTML src attribute and the video appears.

Comment: @Abdrew what about if you append the source tag in video tag... did you try it?

Comment: Is the issue occurring in IE or else?

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to add .load() at the end of each .attr() call to force the source to refresh itself.

Comment: Actually you need to call the `<video>`'s  `load` method (`$("#epv-mp4").parent().load()`)